# Event moved to shared calendar and i am not getting the new calendar name in google calendar push notification

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API and when the event is moved to the shared calendar, I am not getting the name of the new calendar in the response to push notification like when the event is canceled on the same calendar I am getting organizer property in which I am getting the email Id but same is missing when event is moved to shared calendar. Is there any way to know the name of the shared calendar? please refer to attached image for more clarification.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back if the calendar details refreshed?

Comment: What do you mean? above is the screenshot of the response of Google calendar API explorer. Can You please describe in depth?